# Where's the helm of the ISS?

Tags: iss, attitude

...or whatever is the closest thing to it. Probably some laptop workstation, I guess.

In other words - where, inside the station is the console that is used to control ISS when it performs maneuvers - reboosts, rotation in case of incoming coronal mass ejection, rotation before separation of a craft, and so on. Is there a "traditionally dedicated" console for that, or is "whatever laptop is at hand currently" used for pulling up the interface and performing the maneuvers?

Comment: I'd be a little surprised if it's controlled from within the station to any extent beyond pushing a button.

Comment: It's in Houston and Korolev, on Earth.

Comment: There aren't really any consoles in the Star Trek sense.  The crew interface is pretty much all via laptop.  So your latter option of "whichever laptop is at hand is close." But, as others have said, all maneuvers are planned and executed by the ground.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentially, there isn't one. Most of the planning and monitoring is done on the ground, and the execution is for the most part performed by automated guidance, control, and navigation systems.

In the case of reboosts, cosmonauts and astronauts monitor the operation, but this is as a contingency backup to a contingency backup. In the case of proximity operations, astronauts and cosmonauts do again monitor the operations visually and via displays. In the case of automated rendezvous, they can command the rendezvousing spacecraft to abort the rendezvous. This should never happen; rendezvousing spacecraft are supposed to detect problems before they become visible. The cosmonauts and astronauts are backup contingencies in case all of the other backups have already failed.

Comment: And where do they perform these 'contingency of contingency' actions from?